# Get last row of parent table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have projects who inside of it have designs. So one project can have multiple designs.

Project table:

```
+------------+------+
| ProjectKey | Name |
+------------+------+
```

ProjectDesignTable:

```
+------------+-----------+
| ProjectKey | DesignKey |
+------------+-----------+
```

Design Table:

```
+-----------+------+--------------+----------------+-----------------+
| DesignKey | Name | DesignNumber | DesignTypeGuid | ParentDesignKey |
+-----------+------+--------------+----------------+-----------------+
```

So I have a select query like this:

```
SELECT
      *
      FROM [project] AS [p]
          INNER JOIN [ProjectDesign] AS [pd] ON [p].[ProjectKey] = [pd].[ProjectKey]
          INNER JOIN [Design] AS [d] ON [d].[DesignKey] = [pd].[DesignKey]
      WHERE [d].[DesignTypeGuid] = '54FBBC23-CB9A-4311-9D7F-0DD7A774F33D'
```

There I get all designs in each project who have this `DesignTypeGuid: '54FBBC23-CB9A-4311-9D7F-0DD7A774F33D'`

That I want to achieve is to get rows after first design key of each project for example if I have this:

```
    +------------+--------------+-----------+----------------------------------------+-----------------+
| ProjectKey | DesignNumber | DesignKey |               DesignType               | ParentDesignKey |
+------------+--------------+-----------+----------------------------------------+-----------------+
|        152 |            1 |       187 | '54FBBC23-CB9A-4311-9D7F-0DD7A774F33D' | NULL            |
|        152 |            2 |      1316 | '54FBBC23-CB9A-4311-9D7F-0DD7A774F33D' | NULL            |
|       1171 |            1 |      1206 | '54FBBC23-CB9A-4311-9D7F-0DD7A774F33D' | NULL            |
|       1171 |            2 |      1317 | '54FBBC23-CB9A-4311-9D7F-0DD7A774F33D' | NULL            |
|       1171 |            3 |      1401 | '54FBBC23-CB9A-4311-9D7F-0DD7A774F33D' | NULL            |
+------------+--------------+-----------+----------------------------------------+-----------------+
```

My desire result is to get:

```
 152 |            2 |      1316 | '54FBBC23-CB9A-4311-9D7F-0DD7A774F33D'
1171 |            2 |      1317 | '54FBBC23-CB9A-4311-9D7F-0DD7A774F33D' 
1171 |            3 |      1401 | '54FBBC23-CB9A-4311-9D7F-0DD7A774F33D'
```

Once I get this I want to update ParentDesignKey column of each one with first designKey of each project I.E, for this row:

```
152 |            2 |      1316 | '54FBBC23-CB9A-4311-9D7F-0DD7A774F33D'
```

ParentKey should be updated for `"187"` (DesignKey) of first Design

How can I achieve this?. Regards

Comment: It's good you included sample data and desired result, but the logic is unclear. Why did you keep only 2/1316 for projectkey 152? Why did you keep both 2/1317 and 3/1401 for projectkey 152?

Comment: Because I want to get all designs after first one of each project I mean I want to keep 2/136 because it's after first design of this project 152. Same for project 1171, I have 3 designs into this project, so I want to keep rows after first design @GeorgeMenoutis

Comment: Do you actually need 2 things, a select query like the 3-row example you give AND the update query? OR is the update query enough, and you just tried to get it throught that example?

Comment: The propose of this is to do the update.. but I separete it into two steps to be more clear @GeorgeMenoutis

Comment: Why did you keep many rows for the same projectKey then? Is it possible that a lower DesignNumber has a higher DesignKey, but you must exclude the #1? Eg: If you had (ProjectKey,DesignNumber,DesignKey) rows: (1171,1,5000),(1171,2,1317),(1171,3,1401) which would the desired DeisgnKey be, 5000 or 1401?

Comment: Look, once we exclude first rows. I want to update ParentDesignKey column of current rows with DesignKey of excluded row of each project. As your comment of higher designkey, that's not possible because DesignTypeGuid column. Always first row should be  min DesignKey value @GeorgeMenoutis

Comment: Are you sure each DesignKey is only associated with one ProjectKey?

Comment: Yes I'm sure @GeorgeMenoutis

Answer (score 1):

Here's a cross apply solution:

```
update d set ParentDesignKey=firstDesignKey
from Design d
cross apply
(
    select top 1 Designkey as firstDesignKey
    from Design dfirst
    inner join ProjectDesign AS pd ON dfirst.DesignKey = [pd].[DesignKey]
    where d.DesignKey = [pd].[DesignKey]
    order by dfirst.DesignNumber asc
)q
```

Comment: OP actually wants multiple rows, as seen in desired result and comment response. At least concerning the first part, not the update one.

Comment: OP also wants the MIN(DesignKey) per each ProjectKey so they can update the ParentDesignKey

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand the question, you can use <strike>`lag`</strike> `first_value` to get the value of the `DesignKey` column in the row where the `ProjectKey` is the same as the current row but the `DesignNumber` is lower:

```
SELECT  ProjectKey, 
        DesignNumber, 
        DesignKey, 
        DesignType, 
        FIRST_VALUE(DesignKey) OVER(PARTITION BY ProjectKey ORDER BY DesignNumber) AS ParentDesignKey 
FROM [ProjectDesign] AS [pd] 
INNER JOIN [Design] AS [d] 
    ON [d].[DesignKey] = [pd].[DesignKey]
WHERE [d].[DesignTypeGuid] = '54FBBC23-CB9A-4311-9D7F-0DD7A774F33D'
```

For the sample data you've posted, this query should give you this result set:

```
+------------+--------------+-----------+----------------------------------------+-----------------+
| ProjectKey | DesignNumber | DesignKey |               DesignType               | ParentDesignKey |
+------------+--------------+-----------+----------------------------------------+-----------------+
|        152 |            1 |       187 | '54FBBC23-CB9A-4311-9D7F-0DD7A774F33D' | NULL            |
|        152 |            2 |      1316 | '54FBBC23-CB9A-4311-9D7F-0DD7A774F33D' | 187             |
|       1171 |            1 |      1206 | '54FBBC23-CB9A-4311-9D7F-0DD7A774F33D' | NULL            |
|       1171 |            2 |      1317 | '54FBBC23-CB9A-4311-9D7F-0DD7A774F33D' | 1206            |
|       1171 |            3 |      1401 | '54FBBC23-CB9A-4311-9D7F-0DD7A774F33D' | 1206            |
+------------+--------------+-----------+----------------------------------------+-----------------+
```

Also, please note you don't actually need to join the `Project` table since you are not using any of it's columns anywhere.

Comment: I found a problem there, last two designs have different ParentDesignKey and they should have 1206 both, because the rule is all designs who are after first one have ParentDesignKey as DesignKey of first DesignKey

Comment: Well, just replace `lag` with `first_value` for that. Edited my answer.

Comment: I tried it, but it changes ParentDesignKey to first design too

Comment: Please edit your question with proper sample data and complete desired results so we wouldn't have to guess...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.ProjectKey, max(DesignNumber), d.DesignKey, DesignType 
FROM [project] AS [p]
      INNER JOIN [ProjectDesign] AS [pd] ON [p].[ProjectKey] = [pd].[ProjectKey]
      INNER JOIN [Design] AS [d] ON [d].[DesignKey] = [pd].[DesignKey]
WHERE [d].[DesignTypeGuid] = '54FBBC23-CB9A-4311-9D7F-0DD7A774F33D'
GROUP BY p.ProjectKey, d.DesignKey, DesignType
```

Comment: I don't think this will work.  It looks like `DesignKey` has a different value for each row, so the `group by` will not group them the way you want.